# laravel 6 api resource policy index

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

The policy does not work on the `index` apiResource call. Always returns `403`..

My ProjectPolicy is this:

```php
class ProjectPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view any projects.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function viewAny(User $user)
    {
        return true;
    }
...
```

My ProjectController used this:

```php
class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->authorizeResource(ProjectPolicy::class, 'project');
    }
...
```

I registered the policy:

```php
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        Project::class => ProjectPolicy::class,
    ];
```

Everything works except the `index` method call:

```
/**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->user()->projects()->get();
    }
```

Comment: in which class is the index method? the controller or the api resource?

Comment: @Saly3301 in the controller

Comment: Okay, my answer also uses the controller, it should work

Answer (score 1):

In the project controller constructor, you need to authorize the resource (model) not the policy itself

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->authorizeResource(\App\Project::class, 'project');
}
```

Also make sure that the user making the request is authenticated, can't have guests authorized

But if you want [guests to be authorized](https://laravel.com/docs/authorization#guest-users), you may mark the `User` model nullable/optional on the Dependency injection on the Policy class

```php
/**
 * Determine whether the user can view any projects.
 *
 * @param  \App\User  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
public function viewAny(?User $user)
{
    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps